# ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE Goft_ForeEver_cus(
    customer_Id VARCHAR(10),
    first_Name VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT sys_cus_fName_nn NOT NULL,
    last_Name VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT sys_cus_lName_nn NOT NULL,
    girt_Card_Amount NUMBER(5,2) CONSTRAINT sys_cus_gca_nn NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT sys_cus_email_ck CHECK (email  ='%[^a-z,0-9,@,.,_,-]%' ) CONSTRAINT sys_cus_email_nn NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT sys_cus_pk PRIMARY KEY(customer_Id)
);

ALTER TABLE Goft_ForeEver_cus
ADD CONSTRAINT sys_cus_email_UK UNIQUE (email);


CREATE TABLE Goft_ForeEver_Course_Info(
    course_Name VARCHAR2(20),
    city VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT sys_courtInf_city_nn NOT NULL,
    prov VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT sys_courtInf_prov_nn NOT NULL,
    postal_Code VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT sys_courtInf_posC_nn NOT NULL,
    star_rating NUMBER(1,1),
    discript VARCHAR2(200) CONSTRAINT sys_courtInf_descript_uk UNIQUE,
    year_Build DATE CONSTRAINT sys_courtInf_date_nn NOT NULL,
    court_length Number(5,2) 
        CONSTRAINT sys_courtInf_courtL_ck CHECK( court_length = 'YARD') 
        CONSTRAINT sys_courtInf_courtL_nn NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT sys_courtInf_pk PRIMARY KEY (course_Name, star_rating )
);


CREATE TABLE Goft_ForeEver_favorite_courses(
course_Name VARCHAR2(20),
customer_Id VARCHAR2(10),
CONSTRAINT sys_favCourt_PK PRIMARY KEY(course_Name,customer_Id),
CONSTRAINT sys_favCourt_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (customer_Id) REFERENCES Goft_ForeEver_cus(customer_Id),
CONSTRAINT sys_favCourt_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (course_Name) REFERENCES Goft_ForeEver_Course_Info(course_Name)
);

);
```

Error

> Error report - ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns 02256. 00000 - "number of referencing columns must match referenced columns" *Cause: The number of columns in the foreign-key referencing list is not equal to the number of columns in the referenced list. *Action: Make sure that the referencing columns match the referenced columns.

Comment: PLEASE Always show us all the error message and then make sure we know WHICH line of the code is generating it

Comment: Please just LOOK at the code `CONSTRAINT sys_favCourt_FK1 
        FOREIGN KEY (course_Name) 
        REFERENCES Goft_ForeEver_cus(course_Name,customer_Id),` ?????

Comment: The error that this code throws is different. Please, provide reproducible example.

Comment: Just  a side observation, what's the point of _naming_ all of your NOT NULL constraints?  Instead of "first_Name VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT sys_cus_fName_nn NOT NULL", it's much less clutter in your code to simply "first_Name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL" and let oracle assign the name.  I started working with oracle at v7.3, around 1996, and have NEVER needed to control/know the name of a NOT NULL constraint.  Or most any other constraint, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `Goft_ForeEver_Course_Info` has primary key as

```
CONSTRAINT sys_courtInf_pk PRIMARY KEY (course_Name, star_rating )
```

while `Goft_ForeEver_favorite_courses` that references it has foreign key as

```
CONSTRAINT sys_favCourt_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (course_Name) REFERENCES Goft_ForeEver_Course_Info(course_Name)
```

---

See? You're referencing `COURSE_NAME, STAR_RATING` composite key by `COURSE_NAME` only - that won't work.

Therefore, either remove `STAR_RATING` from the primary key in `Goft_ForeEver_Course_Info`, add `STAR_RATING` to `Goft_ForeEver_favorite_courses`, or redesign everything alltogether.

---

Illustration (SQL*Plus, which points to the error):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Goft_ForeEver_favorite_courses(
  2  course_Name VARCHAR2(20),
  3  customer_Id VARCHAR2(10),
  4  CONSTRAINT sys_favCourt_PK PRIMARY KEY(course_Name,customer_Id),
  5  CONSTRAINT sys_favCourt_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (customer_Id) REFERENCES Goft_ForeEver_cus(customer_Id),
  6  CONSTRAINT sys_favCourt_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (course_Name) REFERENCES Goft_ForeEver_Course_Info(course_Name)
  7  );
CONSTRAINT sys_favCourt_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (course_Name) REFERENCES Goft_ForeEver_Course_Info(course_Name)
                                                                                           *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list


SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you have declared the "course_Name" along with "star_rating" column as composite primary key in Goft_ForeEver_Course_Info table whereas you are referencing only one column "course_Name" in sys_favCourt_FK2 foreign key declaration in Goft_ForeEver_favorite_courses table.